# Is there a cubic $Q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ so that $|Q(p_1)|=|Q(p_2)|=|Q(p_3)|=|Q(p_4)|=3$, where $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ are distinct primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Is there a cubic $Q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ so that $|Q(p_1)|=|Q(p_2)|=|Q(p_3)|=|Q(p_4)|=3$, where $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ are distinct primes?

Clearly there must be at least one $Q(p_i)=3$ and at least one $Q(p_j)=-3$ (otherwise there will be 4 roots of a third degree polynomial)

Lets suppose that $Q(p_1) = 3$ and $Q(p_2) = -3$.

$Q(p_1) - Q(p_2)/ (p_1-p_2) = n$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

The dividers of $6$ are $1, 2, 3, 6$.  $(p_1-p_2) \in \{1, 2, 3, 6\}$

That’s what I’ve got so far.

Comment: what is the source of the problem

Comment: @Quantum my math teacher

Comment: Are you searching for only positive primes or also negative?

Comment: My guess is no because the spacing or gaps of primes somehow requires the coefficient of $x^3$ to be a proper fraction. For instance, $x^3-7 x^2+10 x+3$ interpolates $\{(0,3), (2, 3), (3, -3), (5, 3)\}$, but the $x$ values of these data don't correspond to any prime gaps.

Comment: @aryanbansal $|x|=3$ does not imply $x=3$.

Comment: I did all the possible cases with lot of counts, and the answer is no, but I’m searching for a faster way

Comment: @AlessandroCigna positive, only positive

Comment: See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h392562p3159787

Comment: It should be obvious that there are a lot of examples if we work in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clearly values $Q(p_i)$ can not be all the same since third degree polynomial can take only 3 times the same value. Then we have a following cases:

- Suppose $Q(p_1)= Q(p_2)= Q(p_3)=3$ and $Q(p_4)=-3$, so
  $$Q(x) = a(x-p_1)(x-p_2)(x-p_3)+3$$
  and thus $$-6 = a(p_4-p_1)(p_4-p_2)(p_4-p_3)$$
  Since primes are all different (say $p_1<p_2<p_3$) we have:
  $$6 = |a||(p_4-p_1)||(p_4-p_2)||(p_4-p_3)|\geq 1\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3 = 6$$
  and this means that $|p_4-p_1|$ and $|p_4-p_3|$ are odd so $p_4=2$ which is impossible or $p_1=p_3 = 2$ which is again impossible.
- If $Q(p_1)= Q(p_2)= Q(p_3)=-3$ and $Q(p_4)=3$ we proceed similarly as in first case.
- Suppose $Q(p_1)= Q(p_2)=3$ and $Q(p_3)=Q(p_4)=-3$, then we have: $$p_4-p_1\mid Q(p_4)-Q(p_1) =-6$$ and similarly for all other pairs, so

$$|p_4-p_1|,|p_4-p_2|,|p_3-p_1|,|p_3-p_2|\in\{1,2,3,6\}$$

- If $|p_4-p_1|= 6$ then we have $|p_4-p_2|=1$ so $p_2=2$ and $p_4 =3$ and $p_1=9$ or $p_2=3$ and $p_4 =2$ and $p_1=8$. A contradiction. Similarly we see that all absolute differences can not be 6. So two differences must be the same.

If two of them are 3 or 1 then we have two primes to be 2. Impossible.

If two of them are 2 then we have two subcases:

- $|p_4-p_1|= |p_4-p_2|= 2$ then $|p_2-p_1|=4$ but $4\nmid 6$.
- $|p_4-p_1|= |p_3-p_2|= 2$ then $|p_3-p_1|$ and $|p_4-p_2|$ are odd so we have again two primes equal 2. A contradiction again.

Comment: Looks great! Can you elaborate on why *If $|p_4-p_1|= 6$ then we have $|p_4-p_2|=1$...*?

Comment: $Q(x) =a(x-p_1)(x-p_2)(x-q)+3$ so $-3=Q(p_4)= a(p_4-p_1)(p_4-p_2)(p_4-q)+3$. @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: @Aqua Indeed thanks!

Comment: @Aqua can you please elaborate further? Because q could be not an integer as far as i'm concerned.